# Inheritance in Slim template language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, slim-lang

With PHP using Twig I can do something like this:

layout.twig

```
<html>
<body>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

form.twig

```
{% extends "layout.twig" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="form">{% block form %}{% endblock %}</div>
{% endblock %}
```

login.twig

```
{% extends form %}
{% block form %}
<form>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This way I have a layout for all pages, a layout for pages with forms and login page.

But with Slim I can specify only main layout that is parent for all templates:

layout.slim

```
html
  body ==yield
```

and special layouts for every page on my site:
login.slim

```
div.form
  form
    input type="text" name="email"
    input type="submit"
```

Is there a simple way to realize Twig-like inheritance with more than one level in Slim?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks that I found the solution for Slim with Sinatra:

layout.slim

```
html
  body
    == yield
```

form.slim

```
== slim :layout
  div.form
    == yield
```

login.slim

```
== slim :form
  form
    input type="text" name="email"
    input type="submit"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in Rails it doesn't exist something like template inheritance, but I believe that it isn't necessary with `yield` and `content_for` methods.

For example, you can have a `_form.html.slim` layout:

```
.form
  = yield
```

A `_login.html.slim` partial:

```
form
  input type="text" name="email" 
  input type="submit"
```

And when you want to display a login with the form layout, you should do something like:

```
= render partial: "login", layout: "form"
```

Comment: `render :partial => ...` is Rails-specific, but I use Sinatra.

Comment: @therussianphysicist I didn't know it :). But it could be useful for other people.

Answer (score 0):

login.html.slim

```
= render layout: 'form' do
  form
    input type="text" name="email"
    input type="submit"
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more explanation to your answer?